# Configuring the Logstash Loggly Output to Use Loggly's Batch API

Tags: logging, configuration, logstash, loggly

I’ve been experimenting with [Logstash’s Loggly output](http://www.logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/outputs/loggly), and have noticed that it makes one HTTP POST request for each log event that is read from the input.

My configuration looks like this:

```
input {
    file {
        type => "some-logs"
        path => "/my-log-file.log"
        codec => "json"
    }
}
output {
    loggly {
        host => "logs-01.loggly.com"
        key => "loggly-customer-key"
        proto => "https"
    }
}
```

Loggly [provides a bulk API](https://www.loggly.com/docs/api-sending-data/#bulk) that allows you to send multiple log events in a single POST request. Is it possible to configure the Loggly output to use this batch API instead of the default inputs API?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this isn't possible with the current version of the plugin. Instead, I'm using [Logback Extensions](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-extensions) batch mode and removing Logstash from my solution altogether.